# Telegram bot project in GitHub

Tags: python, github

I'm making a math bot. File tree from GitHub:

```
/mathbot
  /funcionalidades
    __init__.py
    eq2grau.py (imported into config.py)
    primos.py  (imported into config.py)
    status.py  (still no use)
    trigonometria.py  (imported into config.py)
 README.md  (I will fill in later)
 bot.py 
 config.py  (imported into bot.py)
 requirements.txt
```

Would it be good for me to put another file besides `README.md` and `requirements.txt` to make it look better or is it already good?

Comment: _"look better"_? What are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If after running `pip install -r requirements.txt` and running `python bot.py` everything runs fine and it is described in your readme, it should be good.

Additionally for public repos, sometimes it is useful to create a Dockerfile, giving others the ability to start your program as a containerized service.

[Here is a video tutorial for creating a Dockerfile for a Python program](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bi0cKgmRuiA)

Additionally you can add dynamic stats to your Github Readme, to make it look more professional:

[Check out this Repository](https://github.com/anuraghazra/github-readme-stats)